# Flipping Parentheses

Tags: text-editors

I have some text with flipped parentheses. For example, instead of `(text-in-parentheses)` I have `)text-in-parentheses(`

Is there an easy way to flip all of the parentheses in the text? If so, how?

***Update:*** This is a plain-text file, every single parenthesis is flipped. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Is it flipped for EVERYTHING, or just some things within any single document?  Which OS are you using? (please update your post with the answers)

Comment: Thank you, I'm no regex genius (nor am I familiar with windows cmd/powershell) - so I bet someone will beat me to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Powershell

#### Short versions

```
(Get-Content "in.txt" -raw) -replace "\(", "`0)" -replace "\)", "(" -replace "(`0\()", ")" >> "out.txt"
```

Also possible:

```
Set-Content "out.txt" ((Get-Content "in.txt" -raw) -replace "\(", "`0)" -replace "\)", "(" -replace "(`0\()", ")")
```

- Reads `in.txt`
- Writes to `out.txt` (scroll horizontally in the first code sample in order to see the end of the line)

#### Long versions

```
$in = "in.txt";
$out = "out.txt";

(Get-Content $in -raw) -replace "\(", "`0)" -replace "\)", "(" -replace "(`0\()", ")" >> $out
```

Also possible:

```
Set-Content $out ((Get-Content $in -raw) -replace "\(", "`0)" -replace "\)", "(" -replace "(`0\()", ")")
```

#### Explanation

Please ignore the cryptic backslashes for a moment – they are only good for escpaing parentheses which do have a special meaning in regular expressions.

We first replace every occurrence of `(` by `NUL)` (see the [NUL character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)). Then, we replace every `)` by `(`. As a final step, `NUL(` gets re-replaced by `)`.

Using that way, we ensure that we do not do "double replacement", for example:

```
Initial string value:
(test)

After replacing "(" by ")"
)test)

After replacing ")" by "("
(test(
```

**Warning**

The file must not itself contain the sequence `NUL)`. This would lead to misinterpretations of my Powershell script since I used the NUL character as a special indicator (for instance, the same situation comes up when using [green screens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) and wearing green clothes).

Comment: This is what I was trying to do - but way behind you, new to PS but looks a lot better than CMD. +1

Comment: @nerdwaller Thanks. String replacements in Batch might be a good puzzle for [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).SE though :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there are single-step ways to do this, but a quick way is to switch all of one paren to a unique character, like ^, then switch all of the other paren to the proper paren, then switch the special char to the opposing paren.

For instance in notepad:

1. Replace all ( with ^
2. Replace all ) with (
3. Replace all ^ with )

Comment: All I would add is, instead of replacing with ^, replace with a more random pattern like *!@#&! which is far more unlikely to occur in the text.